# Errors when compiling assets on deployment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Forgive my tone, but this is an example of a Ruby on Rails issue that really pisses me off.

We have an application in development (specs below).  When we deploy to our dev server, we:

- svn checkout the branch
- bundle install
- bundle update
- bundle exec rake assets:precompile

On one deploy, all succeeded.  About 30 minutes later, there was a commit to the project *that was nothing functional* (just deleting a config/.yml file from the project).  That commit triggered another deploy, and that one failed.  Inspecting the log shows what looked like a JS compilation error on a JS file included by a gem.  Re-deploying showed another similar error, but *for a different file*.

None of the files for the project have changed.  Most of the gems in our Gemfile are pegged to a specific version, and i inspected the list of gems output from the 'bundle update' deploy process for the deploy that succeeded vs. the one that failed and *they are identical*.

I'm also including the precompile errors from the log.  Any input on where to investigate would be **much** appreciated.

**Application**

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.1.11

**Gems**

```
Using rake 11.1.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using activesupport 3.1.11
Using builder 3.0.4
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using activemodel 3.1.11
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.3.10
Using rack-cache 1.6.1
Using rack-mount 0.8.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.3.7
Using sprockets 2.0.5
Using actionpack 3.1.11
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.3.3
Using actionmailer 3.1.11
Using arel 2.2.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.35
Using activerecord 3.1.11
Using activeresource 3.1.11
Using awesome_print 1.6.1
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.3
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.14.6
Using railties 3.1.11
Using momentjs-rails 2.11.1
Using bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails 4.17.37
Using bundler 1.10.3
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using coffee-rails 3.1.1
Using dynamic_form 1.1.4
Using fastercsv 1.5.5
Using geocoder 1.0.5
Using hirb 0.7.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using jquery-ui-rails 4.1.2
Using jquery_ui_rails_helpers 0.0.4
Using libv8 3.16.14.7
Using mysql2 0.3.20
Using paint 0.9.0
Using pdfkit 0.8.2
Using rack-mini-profiler 0.9.8
Using rails 3.1.11
Using rails-console-tweaks 1.0.2
Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete 1.0.12
Using ref 2.0.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using sass-rails 3.1.7
Using therubyracer 0.12.2
Using tinymce-rails 4.0.12
Using uglifier 2.7.1
Using will_paginate 3.0.7
Using wirb 1.0.3
Using wirble 0.1.3
Using wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.9.9.3
```

**First Error**

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: wrong argument type Object (expected Data)  (in /.../js/jquery.easing.min.js)/.../gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/function.rb:13:in `Call'/.../gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/function.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in methodcall'/.../gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/error.rb:84:in `block in try'/.../gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/error.rb:83:in `call'/.../gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/error.rb:83
```

**Second Error**
(note that this second deploy was manually initiated right after the first, with *literally no changes to the code being deployed*)
    rake aborted!
    TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Data)  (in /.../revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js)

Comment: If the only change was deleting `config/yml`, than I suspect that is the breaking piece of code. Did you try rolling back to a working version and testing that the deploy goes fine? Also, in regards to your dissatisfaction with Rails, what framework have you used that didn't produce confusing errors?

Comment: therubyracer has some pretty long standing stability issues (they're switching to a newer version of libv8 to get around this https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/pull/348) with hard to reproduce issues. I'd try a different js runtime (node works well for me)

Comment: I appreciate your time for commenting!  How would the removal of a YML config cause JS compilation to fail??  Started digging in to this again, and wasn't seeing the problem when manually precompiling.. so i proceeded with an automated deploy.. and it succeeded. NO CHANGES.  @maxpleaner, i hardly think that the "everyone else does it" is a valid excuse; a framework is as useful as it is consistent and intuitive.  That said, i'm strongly-typed at heart, so i'm probably not the best RoR judge :-D.

Comment: @ilasno just to throw out a guess, the YAML configuration file might be expected by some Javascript library to exist. Sometimes it is necessary to create an empty file so that a script can write to it.